# c# same event handler for multiple events

Tags: c#-4.0, event-handling

I am very new to c# and OOP in general, really appreciate your help on this. Right now I am working on a vendor platform which provides a set of API for us use. There are several event handlers in my code which calls the same method. In this method, I have some critical global variables.

The question here is do I need to make this function thread safe by implementing mutex,etc..? I understand that if I have several threads calling same function I have to do it. I am not sure about events though.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm assuming your "vendor platform" is a .Net assembly that you referenced in your project. If it's not the case (for instance it's a web service that you consume) then this answer will be inaccurate and you should probably update your question with more information about your case.*

It depends actually.

- If the vendor platform is multi-threaded, then some of your event handlers can be called simultaneously in multiple thread as your third party lib may fire events from different threads. You'll then have to protect the access to your method.
- If the third party lib is mono-threaded, then it's guaranteed that all of the events will be fired in the same thread, thus all your event handlers will be called one after another and you don't need to protect your method against concurrent accesses.

Answer (score 0):

In short if you are referencing "global variables" you'll need to protect access to them with locks (lock) or ReaderWriterLockShim, as in

```
private static Dictionary<string, PerformanceCounter> _counters;
private static ReaderWriterLock rwl = new ReaderWriterLock();

public static void SetCounterValue(object aName, long aValue)
{
    string key = aName.ToString();
    try
    {
        rwl.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite);
        PerformanceCounter counter = _counters[key];
        counter.RawValue = aValue;
    }
    finally { rwl.ReleaseWriterLock(); }
}
```